# Trying to get last post of a page using facebook SDK C#

Tags: c#, facebook

Im using this code:

```
            var client = new FacebookClient("https://www.facebook.com/{accountname}");
            dynamic result = client.Get("/me/posts");
            List<Posts> postsList = new List<Posts>();

            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
            {
                Posts posts = new Posts();

                posts.PostId = result.data[i].id;
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(result.data[i].story, null))
                    posts.PostStory = "this story is null";
                else
                    posts.PostStory = result.data[i].story;
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(result.data[i].message, null))
                    posts.PostMessage = "this message is null";
                else
                    posts.PostMessage = result.data[i].message;

                posts.PostPicture = result.data[i].picture;
                posts.UserId = result.data[i].from.id;
                posts.UserName = result.data[i].from.name;

                postsList.Add(posts);
            }
```

In the {accountname} I put the official account of the posts I want to retrieve and Im getting this error:

(OAuthException - #1) Bad signature

I just want to show last post of a facebook account, Is there any other way? Or what should i post as {accountname}

Thanks.

Comment: What call is implicitly being made by this client call? You also need access token to make these requests.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work

```
 string app_id = "403769793162381";
            string secret_id = "8bc73e4e6b780b52cfe9c1c6618958cd";
            string scope = "publish_actions,manage_pages";

            if (Request["code"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                    app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}&perms=status_update"
                    , app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), secret_id);
                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
                using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {

                    StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                    string vals = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                    {
                        tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf('=')), token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf('=') - 1));
                    }
                    string access_token = tokens["access_token"];
                    Session["access_token"] = access_token;

                    var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);


                    dynamic mywallPosts = client.Get("/me/posts");
                    List<Posts> fb_posts = new List<Posts>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < mywallPosts.data.Count; i++)
                    {

                        Posts post = new Posts();
                        post.PostId = mywallPosts.data[i].id;
                        post.PostMessage = mywallPosts.data[i].message;
                        post.PostPicture = mywallPosts.data[i].picture;
                        post.PostStory = mywallPosts.data[i].story;
                        post.UserName = mywallPosts.data[i].from.name;

                        fb_posts.Add(post);
                    }
```